# How to secure firebase storage without using firebase auth? (nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Im using firebase storage for uploading files within my `next.js` page. Clients fill in a form and the files are going to be uploaded in firebase storage. (Im using a different database)

I'm wondering how I can only allow uploading files within this post request.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { storage } from "../src/firebase/index";

const ReactFirebaseFileUpload = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      snapshot => {
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(progress);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => {
            setUrl(url);
          });
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <progress value={progress} max="100" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      <br />
      {url}
      <br />
      <img src={url || "http://via.placeholder.com/300"} alt="firebase-image" />
    </div>
  );

}

export default ReactFirebaseFileUpload;
```

This is my working example with open rules.

My rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to put the upload on the next.js api route system, so we have an api to call. In my imagination either I can somehow secure this part then with headers or something OR maybe even better define something in my storage rules.

i really didn't find anything smart to define there.

Please help me guide threw this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone (without Auth) needs to upload data you need to give him `write` access to a specific `path` in your storage.

To get the `donwloadURL` from that `ref` it needs the `read` rights.

If it is possible from your bussines logic that anyone can upload but desn't need the `downloadURL` you could remove the `read` for everyone.

I would deffinitely recommend to upload such files under a specific `path` like "public" and at least make restrictions like file size and contentType like here for images:

```
match /public/{allPaths=**} {
        allow read: if true
        allow write: if request.resource.size < 15 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*') 
    }
```

Don't forget that the `downloadURL` is a public access URL for every file. So anone who has that URL can acess that file. You need the `read` rules to get that `downloadURL` from a reference but if you got the `downloadURL` from somewhere else you could still access the file. They are made in a way that could not ques them very easy so it's is quite safe approach.

You could use the admin SDK to do it on your own if you can and just return the `downloadURL` or use Firebase Cloud Functions with storage triggers to listen for file uploads (with restricted access like above) and store the `downloadURL` somewhere you need it.

[Here](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens) you have a very good explanation how all that can work together.

Comment: Since yesterday I stumbled over firebase admin sdk. Does it make sense to restrict the storage write rule completely and do the upload only with the firebase admin sdk? I have my code on an api route. I could restrict the api route somehow with a secret, so I can control the access. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes. I would recommend that. Just make sure to return the `downloadURL`. I updated the answer to explain the `downloadURL` a little bit more. The nodeJS admin SDK doesn't support the `getDownloadURL()` but you can construct it on your own like shown here: https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, youre already helping me a lot. I didnt find any example regarding to nextjs and my challenge to upload data without using auth in the internet. Could you place a minimal working example in nextjs doing an upload to the storage by using firebase admin sdk and next api routes? That would help me (and I think others too) understand a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long do the files need to be able to read? Maybe a `getSignedUrl` would be enough. But that downloadURL will work only for a max of 7 days.

Comment: the files are used on the webpage, so they need to visible all the time then. Could you provide me a mpv with nextjs and api routes?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with nextjs. Would that `token` to secure the upload be on the client side or server side? If it's on the client side and in your code that is JS I would not consider it much safer than using the `write` rules. If it's on the server side then it would be ok. Dependingon that we have 2 options

Comment: maybe you can clear some more things up. i tried working with the admin sdk uploading the files to firebase storage, but that doesnt work.  it seems that you can upload only to the google cloud storage. is that correct? im using the firebase storage and i want to access it with the admin sdk